# Selecting a complete group of records from other groups based on one row condition

Tags: sql

There is a group of rows which have the losscode and service odom. The contract number and service odometer are used to group the rows.

help me to find the way to select only the row group which have the losscode = 'REVSTD'?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using `in`

```
select * from t where 
     iServiceodom in 
     ( select iServiceodom 
      from t
      where sLossCode='REVSTD')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table t1 
              WHERE t1.scontractnumber = t.contractnumber AND t1.iServiceOdom = t.iServiceOdom AND t1.slosscode='REVSTD'
             );
```